# Cancelling javascript onClick event on condition

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table with multiple columns, one of them is a button. When table row clicked the javascript function is called to modify `windows.href` property, in order to go to another page. When button is clicked, I want the user to stay on the same page and perform different action. I use `onClick` event of the button to do that. The function is called but the user still gets transferred to another page. How can I prevent that, other then moving `onClick` even of the table row to each table cell except the cell where button is located? is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you provide us with a snippet of your code?

Comment: `if (anything){return}` before the action you wanna deal with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `stopPropagation()`. In your event handler, try something like this:

```
function handleButtonClick(e) {
  // Stop click event from "bubbling up" to parent elements
  e.stopPropagation();

  // Other logic ...
}
```

For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation.